# Alternation ("OR") searching

Tags: data.gov, ckan

This seems like a trivial thing, but I can't seem to get basic alternation when searching for databases, eg. `crime OR court`. I briefly looked at the API to see if there was a way to do it through that, but couldn't find anything there either.

I expected this to produce results, but it doesn't:

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=crime+OR+court+OR+justice+OR+pretrial+OR+judicial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AFAIK](https://gist.github.com/davidmiller/f22c2dcb347f3dbc4b16cb8a4bddbc04), at least one `:` should be used in order to enable advanced search on CKAN:

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=title:abracadabra+OR+crime+OR+court+OR+justice+OR+pretrial